# How many Acrobatics checks are needed to pass through a medium creature's threatened area via its space?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, opportunity-attack

I'm trying to understand how using Acrobatics to avoid attacks of opportunity works.

[image]

The green dot is the creature that wants to move past its foe without provoking any attacks of opportunity. The red dot is the foe, and the blue dot is the square that the green creature wants to reach. The light-blue area is the foe's threatened area. Both the creature and the foe are medium size.

Considering that:

- The red foe's threatened area [includes its own space](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67431/is-a-creatures-space-included-in-its-threatened-area)
- A creature has to make [an Acrobatics check for each threatened square it leaves](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67403/for-how-long-is-movement-halved-when-avoiding-an-attack-of-opportunity-with-acro)
- Entering an enemy's space provokes an AoO "should be considered" (IIRC) aside from moving out from a threatened square

Assuming every check is successful, how many Acrobatic checks does the creature need to get from the green to the blue square, through the foe at the red square?

Comment: Corrections of misapprehensions in the question are sometimes better done in an answer. I would say this is one of those cases, given the resistance to correction via comments evidenced so far here and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## One, at +5 DC

The assumption that a separate check is made for each square is incorrect, as indicated by [this FAQ entry](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9nic) provided by HeyICanChan. As both that and the [Acrobatics](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/acrobatics#move-through-threatened-area) table entry indicate, if your move takes you through an enemy's square, you increase the DC by 5, which is the case here.

In addition, it states the following as a special rule for the case of moving through an opponent's space:

> If you attempt to move through an enemy’s space and fail the check, you lose the move action and provoke an attack of opportunity.

Thus, if that check was failed, the green dot would stop in square 1 and lose the rest of its move, in addition to provoking an AoO.

Comment: those assumptions are only other people's opinion. Anyway if the third assumption is true, shoudn't the green creature have to make, when it wants to go from square 1 to the red square, 2 different checks: one for leaving a threatened square and another one for entering a foe's square, for a total of 4 checks?

Comment: Is this ignoring the [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9nic)?

Comment: @Oswald No. "Move through an enemy's space" is listed as an option on **Table: Acrobatics DC's to Move Through Threatened Areas** as an alternative to a more general "Move through a threatened area," indicating that it's a different, more specific instance of an attempt to move through a threatened area.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I could have swore I remembered that it was only one check per enemy, I just didn't have a source for it. Thanks for finding that for me. So my answer is useless in a practical sense (i.e. under normal rules), though it still applies with the given assumptions (could be a house rule I guess).

Comment: @HeyICanChan I don't feel right telling someone "the question is wrong," but I suppose I should. XP;;

Comment: @MikeKellogg At your table, is movement plotted out first then taken all at once *or* is movement taken square by square?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Square by square, generally, which would make the official ruling a little awkward. Though I expect anyone who was planning to move through an enemy's space would know that when they started moving. I'd probably put off checking Acrobatics and AoOs until their entire move was decided, unless the results of that would affect where they planned to move, at which point we're basically down to a case-by-case basis.

Comment: The DC may be higher because of the distance. It's 5ft for moving the first square to the left as it's only entering a threatened square so acrobatics check hasn't started yet, but the next square is +10ft as they are moving at double movement costs, square after that is another +10ft... we're already up to 25ft of movement for them to move the final square they need to use part of the next move action. Or, increase the DC by 10 to move at full speed.